# Tag merge: 'otg' and 'usb-on-the-go'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I just discovered we've got the tags [otg](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otg) (x2) and [usb-on-the-go](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go) (x9). To me they sound as referring to the very same thing (or did I miss another otg feature?).

Suggestion: Make `otg` a synonym to `usb-on-the-go`. I'm already going ahead and re-tag the two `otg` questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

Comment: Tnx! Re-tagging done as well, tag-wiki already was complete ;)